# Problem with Android Studio on Mac System

Tags: android, ios, macos, android-studio, flutter

At work, we are currently trying to program a google flutter app. It works just fine on my Windows PC and now I tried to install Android Studio on a Mac to compile it to iOs. But when I start compiling, this error comes:

[image]

I tried uninstalling the directory /User/localadmin/.gradle several times and I don't know, how to fix this problem. Pls ask me anything in the comments

Comment: It says could not open cache settings..  Goto file Menu -> Select Invalidate caches and Restart now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this error is related to gradle caching. The actual error is `Unsupported class file major version 57`. The version of gradle you use is [not compatible with java 13](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8681).

Compare the version of the Java JDK on your Windows PC and your Mac. I would use Java 11 (instead of 13) on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the C:\Users\localadmin.gradle\caches and locate the subfolder that is being complained about in your error message (e.g., 5.6.2).

Rename that folder (e.g., to 5.6.2_OLD).

Back in Android Studio, do Clean Project then Rebuild Project.

This will then generate a new subfolder (e.g., 5.6.2) in your caches directory and the build should complete successfully.

Comment: I have the exact same error again, it creates the new folder, even the cache folder has the same id

Comment: But you renamed the folder or create a new folder?

Comment: I renamed the old folder

Comment: Remove the \cache file from my \.gradle directory

Comment: it created a new cache directory, got the same error again